# Is this a memory leak? - the Context is the Android Context

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I ran into out of memory exception on my app. I have code that, in general, does something like below:

```
while(true)
{
       A.foo(this);
}


public class A
{
    public static void foo(Context c)
    {
       return;
    }
}
```

Will it leak?

Answer (score 2):

No reference to the `Context` is held after `A.foo(Context)` is executed (according to the code you have provided), so you probably do not need to worry about `A.foo`.

**However**, having a thread that is running a `while(true)` loop that never exits can lead to zombie threads that leak out memory - which is more apparent when it holds a reference to a `Context`.

Comment: Yes, the real code doesn't actually do this busy wait. Just wanted to explain that A.foo() can be called a unknown number of time. the real code is calling A.foo() in onCreate() of the activity, and that is called upon rotating the device from landscape to portrait. after few times of rotating, it runs out of memory. I'm looking of a static pointer to the context that is never cleared and so far can't find it.